# ClickOnce Deployment The remote name could not be resolved: 'WORKFREE'

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, clickonce

I am in need of aid in fixing this problem please. I built and packaged an application which I would like to share by email or by web. Problem is when shared by email, the following issue comes up. How do I update the manifest to avoid this please?

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
                Windows                                             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
                Common Language Runtime       : 4.0.30319.269
                System.Deployment.dll                                : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
                clr.dll                                     : 4.0.30319.269 (RTMGDR.030319-2600)
                dfdll.dll                                                 : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
                dfshim.dll                                            : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
                Deployment url                                                : file:///C:/Users/Owner/APPDATA/LOCAL/TEMP/install/AFDBFrontEnd.application
                Deployment Provider url                              : http://WORKFREE/AFDBFrontEnd/AFDBFrontEnd.application

ERROR SUMMARY
                Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
                * Activation of C:\Users\Owner\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\install\AFDBFrontEnd.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
                                + Downloading http://WORKFREE/AFDBFrontEnd/AFDBFrontEnd.application did not succeed.
                                + The remote name could not be resolved: 'WORKFREE'

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
                No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
                There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
                * [10/1/2012 7:30:02 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\Owner\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\install\AFDBFrontEnd.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
                Following errors were detected during this operation.
                * [10/1/2012 7:30:11 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
                                - Downloading http://WORKFREE/AFDBFrontEnd/AFDBFrontEnd.application did not succeed.
                                - Source: System.Deployment
                                - Stack trace:
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifest(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ManifestType manifestType, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
                                --- Inner Exception ---
                                System.Net.WebException
                                - The remote name could not be resolved: 'WORKFREE'
                                - Source: System
                                - Stack trace:
                                                at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
                                                at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
                No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: You could try using an IP-address in stead of a computer name.

Comment: How? What do you mean use an IPAddress?